# Play Framework - play.data.validations vs. custom validations?

Tags: java, forms, validation, playframework, playframework-2.3

Using Play Framework 2.3.x, I've found that there is a difference between using the annotations in the [play.data.validation package](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/data/validation/package-summary.html) and custom code written in a `validate()` function.

For example, let's say I have Circle.java

```
public class Circle extends Model {
    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    public Double radius;

    public List<ValidationError> validate() {

        List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();

        if(radius == null || radius < 0) {
            errors.add(new ValidationError("radius", "Invalid radius"));
        }

        return errors.isEmpty() ? null : errors;
    }

    // other stuff...
}
```

Let's say I have a form, and in my controller I am using the `bindFromRequest()` method. If I leave both entries blank in the form then I get a flash error on the name field with the default message `error.required`, but no flash warning on the empty radius field. Then, if I fill in the name field and try to submit the form again, NOW it displays the flash error message "Invalid radius" on the radius field.

I don't want the user to have to submit the form multiple times to get the different validation messages to appear. Why doesn't play perform all validation checks at the same time? Is it possible to check validations this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see  Play do not continue custom validations if these from annotations are invalid. As explained in documentation:

[Handling form submission: Defining constraints](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms#Defining-constraints)

> `validate` method is called after checking annotation-based constraints and only if they pass.

Actually you have clear situation in your case as you can remove `Required` annotation from the `name` field and move it into your method.

Other approach could be writing custom validation class for `radius` and using it via annotation as well.